# Problema com deploy de app web ruby on rails pelo railway

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deploy

Estou tentando fazer deploy ROR pelo railway.app, ele sobe o site, mas quebra nas páginas de autenticação e me deparo somente e sempre com estes logs:
=> Booting Puma

=> Rails 7.0.8 application starting in environment

=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options

config.eager_load is set to nil. Please update your config/environments/*.rb files accordingly:

- development - set it to false
- test - set it to false (unless you use a tool that preloads your test environment)
- production - set it to true

Puma starting in single mode...

- Puma version: 5.6.8 (ruby 3.1.2-p20) ("Birdie's Version")
- Min threads: 5
- Max threads: 5
- Environment: environment
- ```
       PID: 7
  ```
- Listening on http://0.0.0.0:6802

Use Ctrl-C to stop

Contudo, meus ambientes estão configurados dessa forma (config/environments/development.rb e test.rb: config.eager_load = false; config/environments/production.rb: config.eager_load = true) e ainda não encontrei nada sobre isso, provavelmente o railway não está conseguindo acessar minha pipeline. Estou aberto a sugestões e a compartilhar mais código.